# Capacitor protection in transformerless power supply

Tags: power-supply, mains, ac-dc, transformerless

[image]

I am designing a capacitor based transformerless power supply for a WiFi-based device which will be on for 24x7, with an input of 230VAC at 50Hz.

For almost 80% of the time, the device would consume 10-20mA or lower & in peak condition will consume 100 -150mA. This circuit is giving me the desired voltage & power. My goal is that this circuit should have a mean life of 5 years with 24x7 operation.

My concern is regarding C1 & C2 because I don't see any other components getting damaged apart from the MOV & the fuse. I have connected the MOV & a clamping resister to make sure the voltage is within limits. C1 rating is 400V somewhat similar to [this](https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/panasonic/ecqe4225jf/panasonic-22%CE%BCf-polyester-capacitor-pet-400v-dc-5/1096448) & C2 rating 16V. D3 is 1.5KE15A

There are 2 things that concern me.

1. I am not able to connect any resistor at the return path of the circuit which is shown in most of the schematics. A 100E 5W resistor quickly gets heated to probably 100 C or more, if I connect a resistor with the higher value it works, but I get lower power. I kept this circuit on for ~30mA load & C1 got mildly heated ( ~10C). I was looking for NTC to connect here. Please suggest what can be done to protect C1.
2. Do I need to consider a capacitor with ~600V rating so that it can have a longer life?

Comment: A resistor isn't needed in specifically the return path; it needs to be in series with the 2.2 uF capacitor C1. Try using a simulator to look at the current that flows when you turn on the AC at a peak voltage.

Comment: Also, I'm almost certain that the 5V zener D2 isn't appropriate for your use case; a proper linear regulator at that point would be wise; something like, make D2 a >= 6V Zener, and add a linear regulator after to get a clean 5 V. **General safety question**: you do make sure that there's no way at all for anyone to touch the circuit during use, right? There's no cable, no USB, no ethernet going into your device?

Comment: ACGND is actually neutral. Calling it a gnd is not wise. C1 should be a X or Y rated capacitor.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The circuit is under enclosure & no data cables or user touching it.

Comment: Tell me GND on the schematic has no connection to actual GND...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a transformerless power supply beyond the techniques capabilities. Typically a TPS would be used to supply a maximum of a few tens of mAs with a dropper capacitor value of 220n, 470n or occasionally as high as 1uF. With a current of 150mA and a typical value for the series resistor of 820R the resistor will dissipate about 20W. With 820R the peak capacitor charge current at switch on is about 339/820 = 0.5A.

Comment: 820E resistor would not supply 150mA current, so power dissipation is much lower than that. Can a 20E NTC protect the capacitor at power on?

Comment: @Chaitannya To do a more precise calculation for you - the current in the series 2.2uf cap and  820R resistor is 230 divided by the square root of 820 squared plus the capacitive reactance squared which is about 135mA which results in a power dissipation in the 820R of about 15W. If you use a 20R resistor the power dissipation in it will be about 0.5W but if you happen to turn the mains supply voltage on at its peak then they'll be a current pulse through the resistor, capacitor and diodes of about 339/20 = 17A.

Comment: I am not sure if that assumption of Reactance of capacitor is zero at switch-on period is correct, the current formula is Vm/reactance.. So at startup, the voltage would be zero, but the current cannot doesn't start from Imax in first cycle unless the capacitor is charged.That is why we have a bleeder resistor to discharge the capacitor.

Comment: @Chaitannya Assume the capacitor is discharged to start with. Now, if you suddenly apply 339V across the series combination of the capacitor and resistor by closing a switch then, for a moment, all of that voltage will be developed across the resistor with none across the capacitor. The bleeder resistor is there primarily to discharge the capacitor after power-down for safety reasons but I also read once in a Microchip application note (AN954) that it acts with the capacitor as a filter to attenuate EMI from travelling back on to the line.

Comment: 17A calculation is still incorrect for NTC. It may be for a few mS or nS, but the precise job of NTC is to prevent inrush current flowing through the circuit.

Comment: That's right, 17A only for a moment, rapidly reducing as the capacitor charges reducing the voltage across the resistance.

Answer (score 1):

1. The resistor is mainly intended to reduce the inrush current when the appliance is first plugged in.  With all capacitors discharged, that current can be considerable, and could damage the components in your power supply, including the diodes.  A lower value resistor would be better than nothing, and would get less hot.  In many designs, the resistor also acts as the fuse, by using a "fusible" resistor.
2. Many gadgets that use transformerless power supplies are cheap and disposable.  The manufacturer will use the lowest voltage rating capacitors they can get away with.  Appliances should really be able to handle very brief power surges of up to 4kV.  So using an over-rated capacitor will help.

But is there any good reason why you don't use an off-the-shelf 5V power supply?  USB adaptors are capable of supplying more power than you need and are cheap and readily available.  That's why so many manufacturers use them now.

Comment: A 1W 120E NTC should do the job IMO. It will prevent large inrush current flowing into the circuit. Also, the Varistor would clamp the voltage to maximum 400V, so protection there as well. Form factor & cost does not allow me to use an external power supply.